# Prevent inclusion of headers into same file in C

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm looking for a way to enforce that certain headers cannot be included into the same file.

To explain the situation further, assume I have the headers

```
a_1.h, b_1.h
```

and

```
a_2.h, b_2.h
```

I want to prevent the inclusion of `_1` and `_2` files into the same file, regardless of if they were

```
a_ or b_
```

Comment: Put the include guards for `_2` into the `_1` files, and vice versa.

Comment: While I agree with the above comment, I would also point out the fact, that the design requiring this is probably a bad design.

Comment: @govind Where would it be defined though? I can't do so from the files themselves and I don't want this to be something passed via the command line.

Comment: @Eugene The reason im looking to do something like this is because I have a driver supporting multiple generations of a piece of hardware. They have defines, particularly for addresses in their register map which are the named the same but different values. I've abstracted the code itself for each generation, so they shouldn't be mixed and matched, but I'm looking for an extra guard to tell me when I've messed up.

Comment: The point that it *will not* tell you that you have messed up. But the compiler will tell you if it finds redefined symbols. So better not to have such a guard.

Comment: @Eugene The case I'm most concerned about is inclusion of say @`a_1` and `b_2`. Here there wouldn't be any collision of namespace and maybe it got included together on accident. I remember looking at some headers, I forget which OS, but they had a check to make sure they were only being included into a kernel build and not userspace. I was hoping there was some similar pattern here, but I guess there is not.

Comment: Create a new header, `ab.h`, that correctly includes the right pair of files, and only ever include that in your other source code. The separate `a_1.h` .. `b_2.h` files are then used only by the one header. Further, this can be extended to handle `a_3.h` and `b_3.h` if necessary(next year? this year?). If there are source files that only work with `a_1.h` (and not with `a_2.h` or any of the `b_*.h` files), so be it.  You'll be doing conditional builds for those source files anyway (but consider whether `ab.c` that conditionally includes `a_1.c` and `b_1.c` (or `a_2.c` and `b_2.c`) would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that mixing the `_1` and `_2` headers is a mistake that needs to be caught, a simple way of catching it is to define and check guard macros to check for mixed usage of these headers and use the `#error` directive to report errors.

For example, the `a_1.h` header can include this code:

```
#ifndef A_1_H__INCLUDED
#define A_1_H__INCLUDED

/* Define header set as 1 if not already defined. */
#ifndef HEADER_SET
#define HEADER_SET 1
#endif

/* Check for consistent header set usage. */
#if HEADER_SET != 1
#error "Inconsistent header sets"
#endif

/* Other header stuff ... */

#endif /* A_1_H__INCLUDED */
```

The other headers will be similar but the `_2` headers will have `#define HEADER_SET 2` and `#if HEADER_SET != 2`.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why introduce another macro instead of checking for the presence of the other include guard?

Comment: @StoryTeller Because there may be several other guard macros for `a_2.h`, `b_2.h`. etc.

Comment: I don't find the need to assign a unique number to each one to be that much better. Still a synchronization nightmare.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's a unique number for each incompatible set of header files, not for each individual header file.

Comment: Somehow that sounds worse

Comment: @StoryTeller So suggest your own answer.

Comment: And repeat the spiel of using the preprocessor why? I'm trying to understand the rationale you have. So far you haven't been that clear on the benefits. If you are gonna get defensive, well...

Comment: @StoryTeller The rationale is in OP's question: "I want to prevent the inclusion of `_1` and `_2` files into the same file, regardless of if they were `a_` or `b_`." I take that as OP wanting to enforce mutually exclusive sets of included files.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood the OP on that point. Your approach makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that ANY other file in the build process can include a header. With the typical include guard: `#ifndef MYHEADER \n #include MYHEADER`, the header code is only inserted on the first instance. After that, the compiler has eaten it and remembers and doesn't need to include it again. Think of compiling as putting ALL the source code into one file and turning that into a binary. (you know, "compiling" as in putting it all in a pile).  So it's not "into the same file" it's "into the same build".

You want a header file to be mutually exclusive with another header file. (Like, say, if you've got code that targets specific hardware via includes, and you obviously can't build towards two chips at the same time.) First off, if that's an issue, you should really have a single place where such things are defined (like the build script) so that's not a problem. But if you want a simple safeguard:

```
#ifndef PPC_e6500
#define PPC_e6500
#ifdef LINUX
#error This processor ain't big enough for the both of us, Tux. This here's 8548 territory!
#endif
```

That will fail to build and you can figure out who did whatever horrible thing that tried to build towards two targets at once.